# How to manage state of many video players in a proper way?

Tags: reactjs, architecture, state-management

I'm building an interactive video player where the parts of one video are playing in different players to provide smooth switching between them. (User should not see black screen)

Initially I did a global redux state where I had an array of all players and ID of the active player. Whenever the ID of the active player changes I need to update all other players but not the active one.

But when I update one player in that array, all others are beeing updated, and it's not the behaviour I need.

I'm asking for the thoughts of architecture / state-management system I should implement to do this in a right way.

I'll trully appreciate any advises / thoughts / tutorials related to this problem.

Comment: Is it just a coding error?  You say '...I need to update all other players but not the active one' but also 'update one player in that array, all others are being updated', which is a bit unclear.

Comment: How many videos are there that need to be standing by?  What devices are users using?